# JavaFX: ObservableArrayList adding elements freezes application

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin

In my JavaFX application I try to set `choicebox` items (around 90 string items) like this:

```
private fun initChoiceBox(choiceBox: ChoiceBox<String>, elements: List<String>) {

    val detectLabel = "Detect language"

    choiceBox.items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(detectLabel)

    choiceBox.selectionModel.selectFirst()

    choiceBox.items.addAll(elements) // hanging is here

}
```

The method above is called from `javafx.concurrent.Task`#onSucceeded:

```
private fun initializeSelectLanguage() {


    val task = GetSupportedLanguagesTask()

    task.onSucceeded = EventHandler { _ ->

        val value = task.value

        val elements = value.langs.map { it.value } // around 90 elements in my case

        initChoiceBox(selectLanguage, elements)
        initChoiceBox(translationLanguage, elements)

    }

    task.onFailed = EventHandler {
        println(it.source.message) // todo
    }

    executor.submit(task)
}
```

How can I fix this freezing? How can I update my view then if there are too many items to insert to the view?

**Update 1**

I create my `ChoiceBoxes` like this (using `fxml` files):

```
        <HBox>
            <StackPane>
                <ChoiceBox fx:id="selectLanguage"/>
            </StackPane>
        </HBox>
```

The root `StackPane` of the `fxml` file points to the controller class like this:

`fx:controller="com.pany.view.Controller"`

And controller initializes similar to this example:

```
    class Controller : Initializable, Disposeable {

    @FXML
    private lateinit var selectLanguage: ChoiceBox<String>

    @FXML
    lateinit var translationLanguage: ChoiceBox<String>

    private val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)

    override fun initialize(location: URL?, resources: ResourceBundle?) {
        initializeSelectLanguage() // method is already posted above
    }

    override fun dispose() {
        executor.shutdownNow()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using TornadoFX instead?

Comment: 1. does initChoiceBox() happen on JavaFX Application thread? 2. How do you create these comboboxes?

Comment: @AdamArold cause I didn't hear about this

Comment: @SergeyGrinev Yes, I've checked it as `Platform.isFxApplicationThread()`. Comboboxes described in my `fxml` file with controller class attached to the root pane. Also controller class implements `javafx.fxml.Initializable` interface. I'll update the question

Comment: I **definitely recommend** using TornadoFX then. It will be an infinitely better experience from Kotlin than JavaFX, and it uses JavaFX, so you get the best of both worlds: https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/

Comment: @AdamArold so I've tried your framework out. It looks cool but my view hangs the same way c:

Comment: It is not mine, it was written by someone else.